# sendSignedTransaction throws "Invalid Sender

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, infura

I was trying to save the content of a donation form to a blockchain but when I try I get Error: Returned error: invalid sender at Object.ErrorResponse. Can someone please help me?

```
const contractABI = require('./build/contracts/DonationContract.json');
const { Transaction } = require('ethereumjs-tx');

const MAX_TIME_FRAME = 60; // Adjust the maximum time frame as needed
const provider =new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/+ infura key');//'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
require('dotenv').config();


try {
    
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const contractAddress = "0x";
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI.abi, contractAddress);

    const transactionObject =  contract.methods.createDonation(
      formData.street_address,
      formData.pickup_date,
      formData.pickup_time,
      formData.availability_date,
      formData.pickup_hours,
      formData.item_type,
      formData.other_item,
      formData.item_description,
      formData.quantity,
      formData.requires_refrigeration,
      formData.best_consumed_date,
      formData.partial_donation
    ); 
    const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
    const fromAddress = 'etheruem address';


    const tx = new Transaction({
      nonce: await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress),
      to: contractAddress,
      data: transactionObject.encodeABI(),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(await web3.eth.getGasPrice()),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(500000),
      value: web3.utils.toHex(0),
    });

    tx.sign(Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
    {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(result);
      };
    }
```

Can someone please assist me.

Comment: I added this  line to my code as suggested, but it generated another error:                     const tx = new Transaction(Tx, {'chain':'sepolia', 'chainId':'11155111'});                                         Error: Chain with name sepolia not supported
    at Common._getChainParams (/

Answer (score 0):

[From docs example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction), you have to mention the chain

```
var tx = new Tx(rawTx, {'chain':'ropsten'});
```

If you read the note on the same link

> When using ethereumjs-tx@2.0.0 if you don’t specify the parameter
> chain it will use mainnet by default.

Comment: I try that and i am getting an error 
Error: Chain with name sepolia not supported
    at Common._getChainParams (/home/cougarnet.uh.edu/fmnartey/AI-FEED/donation-module/node_modules/ethereumjs-common/dist/index.js:58:15)
    at Common.setChain (/home/c

Comment: can you update npm packages to the latest version

Comment: Done but its still not working